# Existance of matrices such that their left null space contains another matrix with given dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times c}, n>c$. Let $\operatorname{rank}(A)\leq c$. Hence the dimensions of the left null space of $A$ should be at least $n-c$. Given $B\in\mathbb R^{n\times d}$, if $d\leq n-c$, then $\operatorname{rank}(B)\leq\operatorname{N}(A^\top)$. Is this argument sufficient to say that there will exist $\bar A\neq 0$ that satisfies $\bar A^\top B=0$?

It also makes intuitive sense that the non-trivial solution space of $A^\top B=0$ given $B$ can be of any rank, i.e., $1\leq \operatorname{rank}(\bar A)\leq c$ and is independent of the magnitude of vectors of $\bar A$ in the solution space, since, we can arbitrarily fix the norm of each vector in $A$ and "rotate" them until they are perpendicular to the column space of $B$.

Does this make sense and what would be the correct way to prove this?

Comment: The row-rank and column rank of $B$ are equal, so the row-rank is no more than $(n-c)$; that means that the row-nullity is at least $c$, i.e., there are at least $c$ independent row vectors $u_1, \ldots, u_c$ with $u_i B = 0$ for each $i$. If we place these vectors $u_1, \ldots, u_c$ into a matrix and call it $C$, then we'll have $CB = 0$. Letting $\overline{A} = C^t$ then gets you the result you asked for...but $\overline{A}$ doesn't really have anything to do with $A$. Was that your intention?

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. For the second thing regarding magnitude, can we say something like $A^\top B=0\implies\operatorname{diag}(\lambda)A^\top B=0$, for some vector $\lambda\neq 0$?

Comment: I don't understand the use of magnitude here, but ... if $A^tB = 0$, then $M (A^tB) = 0$ for any matrix $M$ with the appropriate number of columns, hence surely for any diagonal matrix (with the right number of columns).